# How to: Open double-space delimited file & skip first line

Tags: c#, linq, list

This might be a very simple question for you, but I'm stumped.  I'm trying to read text file that has double-space as the delimiter.

```
"ColHdr1"  "ColHdr2"  "ColHdr3"  "ColHdr4"  "ColHDR5"
"fu"  "bar"  1  2  3
"lorem"  "ipsum"  5  6  7
```

I want to put all the lines into a list except the header line.  This is the code that I have so far:

```
string prnFile = @"c:\temp\test.prn";

var fileLines = new List<string>();

foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(prnFile, Encoding.GetEncoding(1250)).Skip(1))
{
    fileLines.Add(line.Split(new[] { "  " }, 
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
}
```

In the end, I want the list to look like:

```
"fu"  "bar"  1  2  3
"lorem"  "ipsum"  5  6  7
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It would help if you'd say what result you're currently getting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks okay to me at first sight, but I'd use LINQ all the way:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(prnFile, Encoding.GetEncoding(1250))
                .Skip(1)
                .Select(line => line.Split(new[] { "  " }, 
                                          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                .ToList();
```

That will get you a `List<string[]>`. It seems to work for me, but note that it *won't* strip the double-quotes from the start/end of your strings.

If you really want a flattened list, that's remarkably easy - just change `Select` to `SelectMany`:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(prnFile, Encoding.GetEncoding(1250))
                .Skip(1)
                .SelectMany(line => line.Split(new[] { "  " }, 
                                          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                .ToList();
```

That gives you:

```
"fu"
"bar"
1
2
3
"lorem"
"ipsum"
5
6
7
```

Comment: @ChuckSavage: Not to get a `List<string[]>`, no. It's not really clear what the OP's trying to do. Will edit though.